# Wordpress display problems on iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, wordpress, ipad

I have a WordPress site, `allthingsbahai.net`, running `WordPress version 4.7.9`, that is no longer displaying correctly on iPhones and iPads. When the site first loads, the logo displays correctly. On subsequent pages, including the home page, the logo is overly large and distorted. What is strange is that the logo displays correctly on `Android phones`, and also on the computer regardless of how small the browser window becomes, so it seems to be specific to iPhones and iPads.

We have tried using different images for the logo, but they all act the same. This problem has only developed in the last month or so. Before that, it was working fine.

I have a companion site, `bahaistudiesinthecovenant.com`, running `WordPress version 4.7.9`, using the exact same logo image, which displays correctly on all devices.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi I checked you use the https://themegrill.com/themes/accelerate/ theme which already responsive and when I check your site http://allthingsbahai.net/ on mobile devices it looks desktop version so first check in settings of theme have you turn off responsive mode?

Comment: I got it to work by specifying the size of the logo in pixels in the main css file. It's still odd that it worked incorrectly only on iPhones and iPads though.